# Up to date DynamoDB capacity unit count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to see up-to-date DynamoDB total read and write capacity usage, maybe by day, and ideally by table? I know basically how to calculate it, and I can pull the value on responses, but I’m just barely starting to try the service out to see if it’s feasible to use, and I’d like to just throw a bunch of data and a bunch of queries at it, then see overall how much that’s going to cost, without waiting for the monthly bill.

Is this possible, or would I just need to keep track of all of my individual requests and add the results up?

Comment: If you sure what you need, then you can set it up to auto-scaling or on-demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudWatch can show you the `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` and `ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits` metrics per table, and a granularity of up to 1 hour.

Using the console, go to the CloudWatch service, and choose 'Metrics' in the left hand menu.
From there you can choose 'DynamoDB' -> 'Table Metrics' -> and then choose which table you want capacity usage of.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Clearly I don't have much experience with AWS administration, so this helps a lot. I had to fiddle with the options a bit to see the sum instead of average, and do Number instead of a Line graph, but that shows exactly what I was expecting to see. Thank you.